# async/await performance compared to URLSession

Tags: swift, async-await, urlsession

I'm beginner and `async/await` topic makes more so confused and can't really figure out what is the benefit of using it over `URLSession`

for example I have 3 set of data that I need to fetch them, currently I call the first one, and when it's done, I add the second one on its `completion`.

```
public func example1() {
    
    NetworkingModels.shared.fetchFirstSet(completion: { events in
        switch events {
            
        case .success:
            example2()
            completion(.success(()))
        case .error(let error):
            Logger.logError(error)
        }
    })
}


public func example2() {
    
    NetworkingModels.shared.fetchSecondSet(completion: { events in
        switch events {
            
        case .success:
            example3()
            completion(.success(()))
        case .error(let error):
            Logger.logError(error)
        }
    })
}


public func example3() {
    
    NetworkingModels.shared.fetchThirdSet(completion: { events in
        switch events {
            
        case .success:
            completion(.success(()))
        case .error(let error):
            Logger.logError(error)
        }
    })
}
```

And if I make the function async and use new `async/await`. call them like that

```
Task {
   await example1()
   await example2()
   await example3()
}
```

What would be the benefit (except the cleaner code)?

and for example, here I have a function to get the html of an URL, it's written with `URLSession`

```
public func getHTML(url: String, completion: @escaping Result<String>.Completion) {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    
     if let userAgent = Settings.Generic.userAgent {
        sessionConfiguration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["User-Agent": userAgent]
    }
        
    let session = URLSession.init(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
        
        if error != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.error(HTMLError.failedToExtractHTML))
            }
        }
        
        if let data = data {
            if let html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                completion(.success((html)))
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

So if I change it to be `sync/await` it makes the process faster? more reliable? What is the benefit here?
I would be grateful if someone can make it more clear to me. Thanks

Comment: `except the cleaner code` isn't that enough? Besides, you can use `await` with `URLSession` too. Some quick googling shows [this article](https://tanaschita.com/20221017-using-urlsession-with-async-await/) : `let (fileURL, response) = try await URLSession.shared.download(from: url)`. Without `await`, if you wanted to perform multiple async operations one after the other, you'd have to start them inside the previous one's `dataTask` handler. Try doing that with a loop

Comment: No the cleaner code is enough, wanted to know more benefits about it. Because if it's like that, there will no much different between them if there is only one API call?

Comment: With completion handler arguments, you can accidentally forget to call the handler, especially in nested/complicated code spread over multiple methods. With async/await, this cannot happen.

Comment: People have [written extensions](https://medium.com/swlh/extend-urlsession-and-never-forget-resume-again-4e4e361b1460) so they don't forget to call `resume()`. Even with a single call you may want to retry if eg a 429 response is returned. With `await` you only need to inspect the response status code and retry if it's a 429. With callbacks this becomes a lot harder

Comment: *async/await ...compared to URLSession* is comparing apples and oranges. URLSession provides both completion handler and async/await APIs. The benefit of the latter is more efficient thread handling, *quasi-synchronous* syntax and the ability to hand over errors. Please watch WWDC 2021 video [Use async/await with URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10095/)

Comment: Thank you so much for all of you. I cannot add vote your response probably because I'm new here.  It's now more clear to me

Comment: One big benefit of using `async`/`await` over closure completion systems, is  when you have multiple calls that need to be chained. For a single call, it's not that much difference. For instance, in your case, if you added completion closure to `exampleN(completion:)`, then it'd be: `example1{ example2 { example3 {didEnd() }}}`, which could be quite harder to read/debug  at some point later.

Comment: Decorating the function with async does not make the function automatically “async await“ you should watch “Meet async/await”. You aren’t even scratching the surface yet. You can’t combine completion handlers and async await without a continuation.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question at hand, but I would advise against `HTMLError.failedToExtractHTML` if the `dataTask` failed. You are throwing away the error object that was supplied (and thus the caller has no way of knowing *why* it failed. Just use the error object that was returned to you. Also, remember to `finishTasksAndInvalidate` if creating new `URLSession` objects, or else you will leak. Or much better, don’t create a new `URLSession` object for every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out:

- The question is not `async`-`await` vs. `URLSession`, but rather, when using `URLSession`, do you want to use the old completion handler pattern (or even older delegate pattern) or do you want to use the newer Swift concurrency with its `async`-`await`.
- We do not adopt Swift concurrency and its `async`-`await` for performance reasons. (It can be marginally more efficient for reasons beyond the scope of this question, but it generally is not material.) We do it because it lets us write better code more easily:

  - For example, in `getHTML`, did you notice that you have multiple paths of execution (if the URL was invalid; if the `String` conversion failed) where you completely fail to call the completion handler? With Swift concurrency, the compiler would warn you of that error.
  - In completion block patterns, the code in the block will generally be called later than code later in the function. E.g., the `resume` function is called *before* the code in the completion block. In this case, it is not too hard to reason about, but in more complicated scenarios, it becomes hard to follow. Swift concurrency eliminates that.
  - In completion block patterns, managing dependencies between multiple tasks that are, themselves, asynchronous, quickly becomes unwieldy. You can end up with completion blocks inside completion blocks, which can become quite hard to grok. To address this, we would often resort to other patterns (`Operation` objects, futures/promise libraries, Combine, etc.), many of which are quite complicated, themselves. Swift concurrency eliminates all of that.
  - In completion block patterns, there is usually a complicated “completion” closure parameter (which you have apparently omitted from your `example1`, `example2`, etc., code snippets) with its own `Result` parameter. In `async`-`await` patterns, you simply `return` values and `throw` errors. A lot of the syntactic noise just disappears.
  - Note, in the old GCD completion handler pattern, we often manually dispatch completion handlers back to the main queue. (In `getHTML`, you are doing this for errors but curiously not for successes.) In Swift concurrency, you simply mark methods or classes that have to happen on the main actor (e.g., with `@MainActor`). That almost always eliminates the need for the called function to manually “dispatch” stuff back to the main queue/actor. The compiler can take care of much of this for you.

---

For what it is worth, here is a `async`-`await` rendition of `getHTML`:

```swift
public func getHTML(url: String) async throws -> String {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { throw URLError(.badURL) }

    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    if let userAgent = Settings.Generic.userAgent {
        sessionConfiguration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["User-Agent": userAgent]
    }

    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
    defer { session.finishTasksAndInvalidate() }                   // if you're going to create `URLSession` instances, clean up after yourself

    let (data, _) = try await session.data(from: url)

    guard let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
        throw HTMLError.failedToExtractHTML
    }

    return string
}
```

This is a simple, direct translation of the question’s GCD-based code to `async`-`await`. Unrelated to the question at hand, if you are going to create sessions like this, make sure to `finishTasksAndInvalidate`, or else each `URLSession` instance is going to leak a little memory.

Frankly, you really should not even be creating a new `URLSession` for each request (you would create it once and reuse it). Perhaps something like:

```swift
let session: URLSession = {
    let configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = .default

    if let userAgent = Settings.Generic.userAgent {
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["User-Agent": userAgent]
    }

    return URLSession(configuration: configuration)
}()

public func getHTML(url: String) async throws -> String {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { throw URLError(.badURL) }

    let (data, _) = try await session.data(from: url)

    guard let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
        throw HTMLError.failedToExtractHTML
    }

    return string
}
```

Frankly, I'm not sure why the user agent is even an optional, but that is beyond the scope of this question. But hopefully, this illustrates how `getHTML` could be refactored with `async`-`await`.

---

I might suggest watching WWDC 2021 video [Meet async/await in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/), which is a good introduction to this topic. There are other videos linked to on that page that are also illuminating.